# How to set more automatic levels on contour plot with Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, contour

I am plotting the following picture

[image]

with the following code

```
plt.pcolormesh(ticks[0], ticks[2], np.transpose(potential), zorder=0)
plt.contour(ticks[0], ticks[2], np.transpose(potential), zorder=1, colors='black', linestyles='solid')
plt.pcolormesh(ticks[0], ticks[2], np.transpose(rectangle), cmap=ListedColormap([[1, 1, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1]]), zorder=2)
```

Now I want more contour levels. If I code

```
plt.contour(ticks[0], ticks[2], np.transpose(potential), zorder=1, colors='black', linestyles='solid', levels=100)
```

(or any other integer) I get the warning

```
/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/contour.py:1180: UserWarning: No contour levels were found within the data range.
```

and picture without contour at all

[image]

How to overcome?

Answer (score 0):

I was to write

```
plt.contour(ticks[0], ticks[2], np.transpose(potential), 100, zorder=1, colors='black', linestyles='solid')
```